# How can I add arguments to a piped script in fish shell?

Tags: arguments, pipe, fish

I am looking for a way to add arguments to a piped curl script which shall be executed in a fish shell. In my case, this is installation of oh-my-fish via curl.

The command without arguments is:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | fish
```

But as I want to run this in a non interactive environment, I want to add the arguments `--noninteractive` and `--yes` to the downloaded script to get something like

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | fish -- --noninteractive --yes
```

This code is just to express, what I want and does not run.

For bash the equivalent would be

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | bash -s -- --noninteractive --yes
```

but I cannot find a way to do this with fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell fish to source stdin with arguments explicitly:

```
curl | fish -c 'source - --noninteractive --yes'
```

The `-` as the filename stands for stdin, any further arguments to source will be used as the $argv, no `--` is necessary.

Alternatively, separate the download and running step:

```
curl > file
fish file --noninteractive --yes
```

Fish stops processing its own arguments after the filename so, again, no `--` necessary.

---

Or, for your problem at hand, oh-my-fish reads the variables "NONINTERACTIVE" and "ASSUME_YES", so you can do

```
curl | NONINTERACTIVE=1 ASSUME_YES=1 fish
```

Comment: I could successfully use the "separate download and running steps" way but I also learned a lot from the alternatives, you described. Thank you for this very informative answer!